# What is the correct way of using void @Published variables in combine?

Tags: swift, combine

Lets assume I have a `ViewControllerA` that presents `ViewControllerB` and I want to subscribe to a button tap. I can do something like this:

```
public class ViewControllerB {
    public var didTapButton = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    ...

    func buttonTapped() {
        didTapButton.send(completion: .finished)
    }
}
```

then subscribe to `didTapButton` in `ViewControllerA` with `sink`.

If I want to do the same with `@Published` variable, all I can think of is doing this:

```
public class ViewControllerB {
    @Published public var didTapButton: Void?
    ...

    func buttonTapped() {
        didTapButton = ()
    }
}
```

Does this make sense? or is there better way to do this?

Comment: Is `didTapButton` a `@Published` property in `ViewControllerB`? What do you mean by a "better way" - what doesn't work?

Comment: yes it is, forgot to add keyword after copy-paste. it works but is it ok to handle things using void variables like that? style wise.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you've shown, `public var didTapButton` is not `@Published`. So the question as it stands doesn't make much sense.

If you wanted to make it `@Published` I would recommend typing it as Bool. Then you just ignore the actual Bool value; it is the signal itself you are after. You would just `toggle()` the Bool to make the `@Published` variable emit a signal. Working with Void signals, as I think you've noticed, is not all that pleasant in Combine.

However, I happen to think that a passthrough subject is a much nicer (and far more powerful and flexible) approach, and I don't see why you would reject using it.

Another thing to note is that the use of the IBAction as an intermediary is somewhat clunky. You can add a UIControl publisher so that you can subscribe *directly* to the button tap. What I do in my own apps where there is this kind of relaying is to `.subscribe` the passthrough subject to the UIControl publisher. The ability to do that is part of what makes a Subject so wonderful: it can itself be a publisher *or* an operator in the middle of the chain, so it can be used to relay the signal from one view controller to another *automatically* — there is no need to say `send` to it. Observe that what I send via the passthrough subject in that example is neither a Bool nor a Void nor a completion, but rather a custom enum that tells the recipient exactly what just happened (in terms of intent).

Comment: See https://github.com/mattneub/CheckWeather/blob/master/CheckWeather/ViewControllers/ZipEntryViewController.swift for an example of the kind of thing I'm talking about. This is a presented view controller with a Cancel button and an OK button and we need to relay the signal from the view controller to a Processor instance.

Comment: I edited the code, missed @Published keyword accidentally.

Comment: I agree, passthrough subject seems more flexible here but just wanted to know what are other options with combine. I started getting familiar with it and got few questions on the way

Comment: Well that is what my answer answers.